# Formatting with astropy.io.ascii

Tags: python, dataframe, formatting, number-formatting, astropy

I have an AstroPy Table of data:

```
>>> data

 ra           dec          redshift ... yMeanPSFMag       yMeanPSFMagErr
 ------------ ------------ -------- ... ----------------- --------------------

 0.34011348  26.83588138     5.75 ...  19.49519920349121   0.03307399898767471
 0.66411726  25.84304425     5.82 ...  19.45319938659668   0.04351300001144409
 1.4680833   -0.1154999      5.85 ...  20.118600845336914  0.18635299801826477
 2.10739     -6.43456        5.93 ...  20.439899444580078  0.16982899606227875
```

and I'd simply like to output this in a control formatted way:

```
>>>  df = data['ra', 'dec']
>>>  ascii.write(df, 'temp.dat', overwrite=True, formats="{df['ra']:%3.1f, df['dec']:%8.3f}")
```

and I get a:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I had a look at [this package](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/master/docs/io/ascii/write.rst) but can't see anything directly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this fairly often. To stay close to what you've written:

```
df = data['ra', 'dec'] 
ascii.write(df, 'temp.dat', overwrite=True, formats={'ra':'%3.1f','dec':'%8.3f'})
```

or my preferred way to do this would be

```
aformats = ['%.1f','%.3f']
oformats = dict(zip(df.colnames, aformats))
ascii.write(df, 'temp.dat', overwrite=True, formats=oformats)
```

bc specifying the total digits isn't often necessary.

Comment: which i realize now, after doing this dozens of times a year assumes I know the order of df.colnames, but often I do.

Comment: This is great Gus. Thanks. One 'bonus' would be to format something such as 1.2345 the same as 234.5678, i.e. f8.4 in old money!

Comment: ah, your goal, Nick, is to center the decimal place in a certain column -- right -- then sure, you'll need the total width (%8.4f). my use case is often to reformat numbers that authors submit to us in a paper that have machine precision (say a RA or a magnitude with picoarcsecond precision) and store that in a CSV file for further processing (into a column delimited format.)

Answer (score 1):

Another feature to keep in mind is that the table itself can store the desired formatting.  This is handy because it always prints nicely, and you can even write to FITS and back and the column format will be preserved.

```
In [2]: dat = Table({'ra': [1.2345123, 234.5678232], 'dec': [20.123, -0.1231]})
In [3]: dat['ra'].format = '8.4f'
In [4]: dat['dec'].format = '8.4f'
In [5]: dat
Out[5]: 
<Table length=2>
   ra      dec   
float64  float64 
-------- --------
  1.2345  20.1230
234.5678  -0.1231

In [6]: ascii.write(dat, format='fixed_width', delimiter='')
       ra       dec 
   1.2345   20.1230 
 234.5678   -0.1231 

In [7]: dat.write('junk.fits', overwrite=True)
In [8]: dat2 = Table.read('junk.fits')
In [9]: dat2
Out[9]: 
<Table length=2>
   ra      dec   
float64  float64 
-------- --------
  1.2345  20.1230
234.5678  -0.1231
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for this. I'm not sure it gets me all the way though. I have a value of -9.9999949E8 and this returns  -999999490.000.